# How to display only the most recent date submission in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a stock data base that I submit data into here is an example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yKsw2LjdkoXZ3TVQICwUjoMIE9uKFA1j1IO9_BFudPQ/edit?usp=sharing). On the right side of the black divider I used the `SORT` function to organize it by sector, industry, and sub-industry. When I resubmit a stock and it'll get tagged with the most recent date. I've highlighted the duplicate submissions to make it easier to spot.

[image]

My problem is sometimes I'll resubmit a stock and the sheet will show all the dates for that resubmission. I only want the submission with the most recent date to show I've tried using the `SORTN` function but for some reason I can't get it to work.

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Okay I've changed the example sheet permissions to anyone can edit, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To to **display only the most recent date submission**, you can use the following formula

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
       SORT(SORTN(SORT({A2:R,INDEX(A2:A&R2:R)},19,0),99,2,1,0),4,1,5,1,6,1,8,1),99,18)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036)
- [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)
- [`SORT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)

Comment: You may want to use a larger number than the `99` I wrote. Try `6^6` *(just to be safe)*.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=SORTN(A2:R, 9^9, 2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1)
```